# Multiple object instances for foreign key in a model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to create an api which will contain data from below two models.
my approach was to filter all activities(start and end time) of same user and then pass that together with user details where the multiple activities(start and end time) will be a list for the unique user

```py
class User(models.Model):
        u_id = models.CharField(max_length=9,default=None,unique=True)
        real_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        tz = models.CharField(max_length=200)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.u_id

 
class Activity(models.Model):
        u_id = models.CharField(max_length=9,default=None)
        start_time = models.DateTimeField()
        end_time = models.DateTimeField()

        def __float__(self):
            return self.start_time
```

User class contains user detail and it's user id is unique.
Activity class can contain multiple start and end time for same user id.

We need an api which will contain multiple start and end time entries for the same user.
I tried querying both models into one querylist and passing that as jsonresponse but it doesnt work.

**views.py**

```py
def user_activity():
    base_url_user = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/'
    base_url_activity = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/activity/'
    res_user = requests.get(base_url_user).json()
    res_activity = requests.get(base_url_activity).json()
    u = {}
    a = {}
    for i in range(len(res_user)):
        u[i + 1] = res_user[i]
    for i in range(len(res_activity)):
        a[i + 1] = res_activity[i]
    
    for u[i]["u_id"] in a[i]:
        querylist = [
            {'queryset': User.objects.all()},
            {'queryset': Activity.objects.all()}
        ]
        return JsonResponse(querylist)
```

**serializers.py**

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *

class Userserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

class Activityserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Activity
        fields = '__all__'
```

**urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewset)
router.register(r'activity', views.ActivityViewset)
router.register('ua', views.user_activity, basename = 'ua')
urlpatterns = [
    path('',include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

**error**

```
E:\fl_project\fl_assignment\user_activity\views.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "E:\fl_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\fl_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "E:\fl_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 396, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "E:\fl_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "E:\fl_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "E:\fl_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "E:\fl_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "E:\fl_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "E:\fl_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "E:\fl_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "E:\fl_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "E:\fl_project\fl_assignment\fl_assignment\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('', include('user_activity.urls'))
  File "E:\fl_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "E:\fl_project\fl_assignment\user_activity\urls.py", line 10, in <module>
    path('',include(router.urls)),
  File "E:\fl_project\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\routers.py", line 78, in urls
    self._urls = self.get_urls()
  File "E:\fl_project\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\routers.py", line 339, in get_urls
    urls = super().get_urls()
  File "E:\fl_project\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\routers.py", line 237, in get_urls
    routes = self.get_routes(viewset)
  File "E:\fl_project\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\routers.py", line 153, in get_routes
    extra_actions = viewset.get_extra_actions()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'
```

Comment: First of all, is there a reason not to use [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) between `User` and `Activity`? Also, the current error is produced, because you need to route a `Viewset` to `'ua'` and not function based view like `views.user_activity`.

Comment: i need multiple start and end time for same user ,i tried using foreign key between them but couldnt make multiple start and end time entries for the same user @rollingthedice

Comment: Okay, so you need multiple `Activity` objects for one `User`? Then `Activity` can have a `ForeignKey` to `User`. When you create 3 activities for example, you can assign the same user for all 3 activies and you will have 3 different `start_time` and `end_time` for a single `User`.